# Why can "trans" be replaced with an x?

Tags: abbreviations, prefixes

I can't think of an example, so I may be wrong about this, but I think I've seen people replace the prefix "trans" as in transport with an x. "Cross" makes sense, as in "railroad crossing", and I guess "chris" is sort of a punny extension, the extension being like "chris cross" and the example being "xmas", but why trans?

Comment: The *X* in *Xmas* is actually a chi, for *Χριστός* (Christ), and its usage goes back some centuries.

Comment: In the late 1990's when dial-up modems were the norm, a friend who was using a university T1 connection bragged (we were discussing using AOL instant messenger) about "sick xfer rates".

Comment: @jlovegren that's right, that's the context I usually see it in.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Trans* is sometimes replaced by *x* as an abbreviation, because *trans* means cross, or across, and the letter `x` as a symbol is a cross.