# Why does XLAT mean 'translate'?

Tags: abbreviations, computing

It is said that `XLAT` is an abbr of `translate`. But I don't understand how come it ends up like that? There is no site on internet would explain it but they're all agree that `XLAT` is shorten of `translate`. I can get that `LAT` is in the end part of translate (`LATe`) but what about the `X`?

Comment: I believe it may derive from a computer programme of that name.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. See *[Why can “trans” be replaced with an x?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200356/)* In short, *X* has been used as an abbreviation for *cross* (e.g. *RR XING*) for some time because it is the same basic shape as all manner of cross symbols (e.g. × ✕ ╳ ✖  + ✠ ✛ ☩ ✚). Since *trans-* means to be across from something, to be at a distance to be crossed, and like meanings, abbreviating *trans-* as *X* has also taken hold especially in technical spheres, e.g. *XFER*, *XMIT*.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

'Trans' is a prefix meaning 'cross', as in 'Trans-siberian Express' or 'Trans-continental railway'.

X is used as an abbreviation of 'cross', thanks to its resemblance to a cross, and despite the shift in meanings of 'cross'.

So XLATE or XLAT is used as an abbreviate of 'translate'. XFER is similarly used as an abbreviation of transfer.

Comment: I quite agree, though I was struggling to find any evidence. X is certainly used in plant breeding for a cross. See under 'hybrid' in [BBC Gardening](http://www.bbc.co.uk/gardening/htbg/module2/plant_names3.shtml) and *xlation* is used to mean "translation" in a variety of contexts, as an online search shows. [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Xlation) redirects me to 'translation' without actually mentioning why!

Comment: Associative xconnections of the brain  xmografes trans to x in these ecrossulent abbreviations ?

Comment: x is also used as a generic word-shortener (consider for example tx for transmit and rx for receive). Is there any evidence that this case was a specific relationship between x and trans rather than just a generic shortening?

Comment: So, this is the True meaning of Xmas

Comment: @PeterGreen it's not a generic word shortener at all. The example of Tx/Rx is an outlier, and it seems [there's no agreement](https://www.quora.com/What-does-X-stand-for-in-TX-and-RX) [on why they were chosen](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/why-txrx)

Comment: @aloisdg Weirdly, yes, kind of. X is also used as an abbreviation for Christ, because of the association of Christ with The Cross.

Comment: @OrangeDog Consider also Morse shorthand such as DX for distance, WX for weather report. Maybe originally from RX (prescription), the origin of which is similarly disputed.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes, those are all mentioned at those links. The etymology of RX (prescription) is not at all disputed though.

Comment: @DJClayworth no, it's because Christ (in Greek) starts with a Χ.